# AceEditor:Uncaught Error: couldn't load module ace/theme/

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ace-editor

I use AceEditor in my code. When I try to save my changes, I get this error

```
Uncaught Error: couldn't load module ace/theme/ or it didn't call define
        at afterLoad (ace.js:18798:1)
        at ace.js:3776:1
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at ace.js:3775:1
        at _require (ace.js:88:1)
        at req (ace.js:138:1)
        at afterLoad (ace.js:3771:1)
        at HTMLScriptElement.s.onload.s.onreadystatechange (ace.js:3397:1)
```

As I understand it, to fix the error, i need to set basepath.However, adding the line `this.editor.set('basePath', 'https://unpkg.com/ace-builds@1.4.6/node-modules/react-ace/src')` in the ace.tsx file does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `basePath` is the folder where ace.js is located. for unpkg it would be

```
ace.config.set('basePath', "https://unpkg.com/ace-builds@1.4.6/src-noconflict")
```

note that the method is on config object not on editor instance.

Depending on what packager you use there may be better ways to configure this.

Answer (score 0):

import ace from 'ace-builds';

ace.config.set('basePath', 'https://unpkg.com/ace-builds@1.4.6/src-noconflict');

Comment: Your answer is the same as [the above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71924357/13927534). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76314057/edit) your answer to include unique information for the asker, or delete it if you have nothing to add.